# Magento add custom tabs to product view

Tags: magento, tabs

I was searching all over the internet and did not find a solution for this.

What I want to do is to do a tabular info system similar to the one that exists in magento modern for product description and other additional information. I managed to do the functional tabbing with javascript. But the problem is that after I added the tabs I am describing bellow the whole page crashes so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Code inside the Tabs.phtml:

```
<ul class="product-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php //if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
            <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php //endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php //if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php //endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I am trying to add few tabs in the product view tabs. 
Here is my code inside the xml file:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>description</alias>
                    <title>Definition</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
                </action>

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>technical</alias>
                    <title>Technical Specification</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_technical</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/technical.phtml</template>
                </action>

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>shipping</alias>
                    <title>Shipping</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_shipping</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/shipping.phtml</template>
                </action>

            </block>
```

And here is the error i get:

```
    Stack trace:
#0 /home/mihaip/work/magentotest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/mihaip/work/magentotest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/product...', Array)
#2 /home/mihaip/work/magentotest/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php(59): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/product...', 'shipping')
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs->addTab('shipping', 'Shipping', 'catalog/product...', 'catalog/product...')
#4 /home/mihaip/work/magentotest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/mihaip/work/magentotest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
```

When i am taking out the *technical* and *shipping* actions everything works fine...
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Do you have all files in place? I mean right paths, phtml and php block files?

Comment: hello, I created the phtml files on the right path. in catalog/product/view.
I am not sure about php block files

Comment: from "manage attribute set", there is one option for adding tab. try that

Answer (score 2):

These modules, blocks and their classes don't exist in Magento **app/code/core/Mage/**:

```
<block>catalog/product_view_technical</block>
<block>catalog/product_view_shipping</block>
```

If you haven't created custom module with these paths and classes in your own package than that's the source of these errors. You created the template views but haven't created controllers in path specified between block tags.

You have two options:

1. Create a module that will handle your custom request
2. Reuse existing controllers to serve you the data and specify their paths in the block sections you specified

Find out more about this concepts from Alan Storm
http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world